# C# load assembly does not bring methods

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-assembly

I am trying to compile a WinForm application (x86) with a reference to the "Interop.SecurityProvider" library.
I've tried different ways to invoke the library, but all the results are unsuccessful.

I have a VM with Win7 32bit, the application is compiling it in x86

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(@"c:\code\Interop.SecurityProvider.dll");
Type myType = a.GetType("SecurityProvider");
MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("User");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
```

when compiling it gives me the following result:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'foo' and non extension method 'foo' accepting a first argument of type 'obect' could be found

**Update**

```
foo.setUrl()
```

Old Code

```
SecurityProvider.foo Foo = (SecvurityProvider.foo)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Interop.SecurityProvider.foo");
```

> Could not load 'Interop.SecurityProvider.foo' from assembly 'bar'

Comment: When compiling or when running?

Comment: Where are you calling `foo`?

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. There is no `foo` in the code you showed. Please provide us with a matching combination of code and error

Comment: @dcg when compiling it gives me the following result

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I'm adding all the code in the click of a button

Comment: if you have a reference to the dll ("with a reference to the 'Interop.SecurityProvider' library"), why are you using reflection *anyway*? why not just `new SecurityProvider().User()` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I get error 80040154, but checking the registry note that the entry is in HKLM\software\classes\clsid

Comment: your example still doesn't explain what `foo` is, and what the method is, in the context **of the code you're asking about**; there is a `foo` in the "Old Code", but... you weren't asking about the old code... re the error: this sounds like COM (you didn't even mention COM, and "interop" doesn't necessarily mean COM - in fact, most interop I see these days doesn't involve COM); so: are you sure you have *registered* the COM dll?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I registered it with regasm 'c:\code\interop.security provider.dll'
Since with regsvr32 I get the error "make sure is valid dll or ocx"